# API for malicious link checking using PHP?

Tags: php

I wonder whether there is any free API for PHP that allows me to check whether a particular URL is malicious (e.g. it contains virus).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like google has one. [Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/)